# Do I need mod approval to get my "idea" moved into the funding required phase on the getmonero.org forum?

Tags: forum-funding-system

What is the process to get my idea into the "funding requred" phase on https://forum.getmonero.org/#category-2 ? Does a mod have to deem the idea valid? What are some requirements for a monero idea?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to post your idea as a link on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/), asking for others to comment, to give suggestions. Optionally, post the FFS Link or Reddit post link on IRC monero-community channel.
Then when a few of us will have asked to move your idea down to "funding required", either ask a Core Team Member on IRC to do it (but they are really busy), or wait for the [Next community meeting](https://xmr.ncrypt.sh/index.php/apps/calendar/p/8dP6z6XQDnkPREo4/Monero-Meetings) to talk about it (with a prepared explanation of your idea and the link to the FFS proposal).